# Change the default output form in Mathematica 11.1

Tags: customization, output

How can I change the default output `StandardForm` to `TraditionalForm` in *Mathematica* 11.1?

Comment: This setting is moved to the Option Inspector [see here](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/28318).

Comment: Does `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],  CommonDefaultFormatTypes -> {"Output" -> TraditionalForm}]` work?

Comment: @kglr it works, but default settings doesn't change..

Comment: @vito If you wish to change the defaults, replace `EvaluationNotebook[]` with `$FrontEnd` in the above comment by @kglr.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in the [Documentation](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/28318),
starting from version 11.1 the format type of new input and output cells can be changed in the Option Inspector.

To change the type of new cells:

1. Start Option Inspector from the menu: 
   `Preferences > Advanced > Open Option Inspector`.
2. Select: `Cell Options > New Cell Defaults > CommonDefaultFormatTypes`.
3. Change `"Input"` and/or `"Output"` to the form you want.